# Issue displaying empty value of repeated columns in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I've got an issue when trying to visualize in Google Data Studio some information from a denormalized table.

Context: I want to gather all the contact of a company and there related orders in a table in Big Query. Contacts can have no order or multiple orders. Following Big Query best practice, this table is denormalized and all the orders for a client are in arrays of struct. It looks like this:

**[Fields Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfgkV.png):**

```
+-------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| Row # | Contact_Id | Orders.date | Orders.id |
+-------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|-  1   | 23         | 2019-02-05  | CB1       |
|       |            | 2020-03-02  | CB293     |
|-  2   | 2321       |   -         |   -       |
|-  3   | 77         | 2010-09-03  | AX3       |
+-------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

The issue is when I want to use this table as a data source in Data Studio.
For instance, if I build a table with `Contact_Id` as dimension, everything is fine and I can see all my contacts. However, if I add any dimensions from the Orders struct, all info from contact with no orders are not displayed. For instance, all info from `Contact_Id` 2321 is removed from the table.

Have you find any workaround to visualize these empty arrays (for instance as null values)?
The only solution I've found is to build an intermediary table with the orders unnested.

Comment: How did you connect your BigQuery data to DataStudio? Did you add a new data source, as described in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6295968?hl=en)?  I have used your data and successfully added a new data source to create a report using DataStudio. Then I created a table as you described and I could see all the values. Do you want me to provide the steps I took ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AlexandreMoraes ! Yes I create a datasource (with the Big Query connector). Is the table you create in data studio with all the dimensions (contact_id,orders.date and orders.id) ? And you are able to visualize the data for contact_id=2321 ? I would be really happy to get a screenshot and the steps. Many thanks in advance !

Comment: @Arthur_H2 Did you find out how to display the information for contact_id=2321? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The way I've just discovered to work around this is to add an extra field in my DS-> BQ connector:

```
ARRAY_LENGTH(fields.orders) AS numberoforders
```

This will return zero if the array is empty - you can then create calculated fields within DataStudio - using the "numberoforders" field to force values to NULL or zero.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this behaviour by changing a little your query on the BigQuery connector.

Instead of doing this:

```
SELECT
    Contact_id,
    Orders
FROM myproject.mydataset.mytable
```

try this:

```
SELECT
    Contact_id,
    IF(ARRAY_LENGTH(Orders) > 0, Orders, [STRUCT(CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS date, CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS id)]) AS Orders
FROM myproject.mydataset.mytable
```

This way you are forcing your repeated field to have, at least, an array containing NULL values and hence Data Studio will represent those missing values.

Also, if you want to create new calculated fields using one of the nested fields, you should check before if the value is NULL to avoid filling all NULL values. For example, if you have a repeated and nested field which can be `1` or `0`, and you want to create a calculated field swaping the value, you should do:

```
IF(myfield.key IS NOT NULL, IF(myfield.key = 1, 0, 1), NULL)
```

Here you can see what happens if you check before swaping and if you don't:

```
Original value        No check        Check
1                     0               0
0                     1               1
NULL                  1               NULL
1                     0               0
NULL                  1               NULL
```